# How to Change Button Alignment in Bootstrap (also using Angular 8)?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

After changing the size of my button with `btn-sm`, it has got misaligned with respect to the rest of the social icon buttons on my `navbar`. How would I recenter it?

[image]

I'm also using `Angular 8` to manage the backend of my website ([maybe that changes something in this case?](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/positioning)); and my top `navbar` is of class `navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light flex-column flex-md-row`.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light flex-column flex-md-row">

  <a 
    class="navbar-brand mr-0 mr-md-2"
    routerLink="/">
      {{ title }}
  </a>

  <div class="navbar-nav-scroll">
    <ul class="navbar-nav bd-navbar-nav flex-row">
      <li 
        class="nav-item" 
        *ngFor="let itemNavbar of itemsNavbar">
          <a 
            [routerLink]="itemNavbar['page']"
            [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"
            routerLinkActive="active" 
            class="nav-link p-2">
              {{ itemNavbar[langNavbar] }}
          </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-md-auto">
    <li 
      class="nav-item"
      *ngFor="let socialIcon of socialIcons">
        <a
          class="nav-link"
          href="{{ socialIcon.link }}">
            <i [ngClass]="socialIcon.icon"></i>
        </a>
    </li>

    <div class="col-md">
      <div ngbDropdown class="d-flex">
        <button 
          class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" 
          id="dropdownBasic1" 
          ngbDropdownToggle>
            {{ upperCaseFirstLetter(langNavbar) }}
        </button>
        <div 
          ngbDropdownMenu 
          aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
            <a 
              ngbDropdownItem 
              class="langToggle"
              *ngFor="let language of languages"
              (click)="onChangeLanguage(language)">
                {{ upperCaseFirstLetter(language) }}
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: You could try to give to the div that holds the icons and the language selector a display:flex (if it hasn't already) and a align-items: center property

Comment: please post complete the code of image attached.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi, I've tried that and, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work either. I've created a `div` to get the `ul` that contains the button and the social icon with those properties but there was no effect. @Plochie, the whole code for the `navbar` is now there.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't *really* solve the problem, but one way to adjust the positioning of this button would be by [adding more margin or padding to it](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/). For example, `mt` will add margin to the top of the button, hopefully you will hit a big enough margin. In my case, I ended up using:

```html
<a class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm d-inline-block ml-2 mt-1 mr-3">
...
```

The number for each margin and padding is a multiplier for the `$spacer` variable found in `node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss`. The `$spacer` variable has a `1rem` measurement by default.